# How to add geant4 module in python IDE?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pythonpath, geant4

Recently I've install Geant4(https://github.com/koichi-murakami/g4python) and would like to import geant4 in IDE like VS or PyCharm. But the ide doesn't see the package. While in terminal i can import geant4. Can you suggest me how to add to the IDE geant4 package, please?

Thanks.

I've tried to add to the PYTHONPATH in terminal (Ubuntu):
`export PYTHONPATH=~/opt/geant4/geant4py-11.0.0/site-packages (bash/zsh)`
like in link: https://github.com/koichi-murakami/g4python